# Error executing phonegap command cordova build

Tags: java, android, cordova, ant

I'm executing the command  "cordova build" (After finishing the above settings, exemplified this link [Phonegap The Command-Line Interface](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)). 
But the note.js returns this error:

> Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
>   Preparing android project
>   Compiling app on platform "android" via command "cmd" /c 
>   C:\Net\Phonegap\hello\platforms\android\cordova\build
>   Error: An error occurred while building the android project.Error executing "ant" debug -f "C:\Net\Phonegap\hello\platforms\android\build.xml"":
>   BUILD FAILED
>   C:\Net\templates\Phonegap\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:601: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Net\templates\Phonegap\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Net\templates\Phonegap\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Unable to find a javac compiler;
>   com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
>   Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
>   It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"
>   
>   Total time: 2 seconds
>
> > at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\myuserpc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\compile.js:65:22)
> >         at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
> >         at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
> >         at Socket. (child_process.js:956:11)
> >         at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
> >         at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)

My config.xml

```
<widget id="com.example.hello" version="0.0.1">
<name>HelloWorld</name>
<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="dev@callback.apache.org" href="http://phonegap.com">
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="WebViewBounce" value="true" />
<feature name="Device">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
</feature>
```

And my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.example.hello" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="HelloWorld" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Comment: What is your question? `Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"`

Comment: My question is, what is missing in the configuration for me to executing command "cordova build".

My path like this:

Comment: `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ROAMING_HOME%\npm;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANT_HOME%\bin`  

JAVA_HOME -> C:\Program Files\Java\jre7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you currently have the **Java Runtime Environment (JRE)** installed.  You need the **Java Development Kit (JDK)**.  You can get that over at [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html).  Your path does appear to be set up correctly with `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`.  I believe once you install the JDK, your `%JAVA_HOME%` environment variable will be changed to something similar to: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_52`.  The version number might be slightly different of course.

Comment: Right, I forgot to pay attention to me that (the principal) I have only the JRE and assigns the `JAVA_HOME` to the path `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7`